# How to know the amount of memory to be used in this program and if it fits in the caches?

Tags: c

I have a nbody algorithm in c, I want to know the memory of that program use and in what cache memory resides. How I can calculate this?
I tried to multiply the n positions of the array by the size of each element of the array and comparare this result with the cache size. I'm right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`valgrind`'s [`massif`](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) tool does what you want. It is a very complete heap profiler.

Here's how to use it:

`valgrind --tool=massif <program>`, where `<program>` is, well, your program. Running this will write the memory profiling data to a file called `massif.out.<pid>`, where `<pid>` is the process ID of the program you ran.

Then you can run the command `ms_print massif.out.<pid>`, which will present you with the output graph showing the memory consumption.

Usage example:

```
valgrind --tool=massif myprogram
ms_print massif.out.12345
```

I strongly recommend that you read the manual that I linked above, as it contains more detailed instructions and describes how you can further use this awesome tool.

Comment: Can you be more precise?

Comment: @Chariot I edited my answer to include some basic instructions. As always, I recommend that you read the manual for the tool! If I answered your question, please consider accepting it so others can benefit from this question. Cheers!